# How can I change the title of the Project Explorer?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-kepler

We are creating an eclipse-plugin with somw views; one of them is the project explorer. How can we change its title from "Project Explorer" to something else?

I understand that there is `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.ProjectExplorer` which has a `setTitle` method, but how do I get the instance used by the Workbench?

Comment: `setTitle` is `protected` so you can't call it except from a derived class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if that is possible.

What you *can* do is implement your own project explorer using the Common Navigator Framework. By reusing tree content providers and label providers from the framework, you will be able to compose your own explorer quickly. It takes some plugin.xml and Java voodoo of course :-)

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fcnf.htm